# Notepad++ Not loading workspace

Tags: notepad++

Usually when I open Notepad++ it shows the workspace I was using previously.

Today however, it is showing a blank workspace and when I select 'Reload Workspace' it says 'Can not find file to reload'

Does anyone know how to find where Notepad++ is storing the loacation of the workspace it is trying to load?

Comment: Have you actually saved the Workspace? I don't think it saves automatically. You must right-click the workspace and Save it to a file on your computer. Or if it's saved on a network share, do you have access to that share?

Comment: @KEK yeah I suspect it is that a network share has been renamed, that's why I wanted to know where Notepad++ stores the workspace location.

Comment: @FrinkTheBrave, So how did you solve the problem?

Comment: I just re-created the workspace